# What's a word for peaking early in a given endeavor?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, phrase-requests

Looking for a word/phrase that expresses you hit the pinnacle of your success early and it's all downhill from there.

"Early bloomer" is the closest I can think of but that implies you learned fast and maintain your level of expertise.

Comment: What do you find is wrong with "peaking early" or even "peaking too early"?

Comment: I'm not making a judgment call on whether it's good or bad I'm simply looking for a word that captures the phenomenon of reaching early success and then being less successful ever after.

Comment: You have to say why you've rejected *peaking*, which does mean what you want to express—at least as far as its been described so far.

Comment: Ah, completely misread that comment - didn't realize Steve was asking what I thought about those phrases. But yeah those are too literal - the answer below is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**flash in the pan**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/flash+in+the+pan) an idiom

> Someone or something whose success or popularity is short-lived.

As in:

> Or is it just another social media flash in the pan?  BBC Feb 24, 2019

Comment: Awesome - this was exactly what I was looking for - thanks!